# How to find the parent element width using javascript when we are using slot

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have one custom element having one div that contains slot.

In that slot, I have JS script where i want to get width of slot's parent div.

I know words are every much confusing :).

[here is the sample code link](https://plnkr.co/edit/8yaSepwywLWnqcCy97oN?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<script>
customElements.define('user-card', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        .name {
          font-size: 24px;
          width:200px;
          background-color: yellow
        }
      </style>
      <div class="name">Name:
        <slot name="username"></slot>
      </div>
      <div class="dob">Birthday:
        <slot name="birthday"></slot>
      </div>
    `;
    this.shadowRoot.styles = `

    `
  }
});
</script>

<user-card>
  <span slot="username">
    <script>
      function abc(event) {
        console.log('Expected: ', this.document.getElementsByTagName('user-card')[0].shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('div.name')[0].offsetWidth)
        console.log('Result: ',event.target.parentElement.offsetWidth);
      }

    </script>
    <div onclick="abc(event)">
      Ritesh Rajput
      </div>

  </span>
  <span slot="birthday">01.01.2001</span>
</user-card>
</body>
```

ideally both should return same value

```
console.log('Expected: ', this.document.getElementsByTagName('user-card')[0].shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('div.name')[0].offsetWidth)
console.log('Result: ',event.target.parentElement.offsetWidth);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second log the element `event.target.parentElement` is the `<span slot="username">`.
A `<span>` is [inline](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-width) and has a width of 0.

You'll had to set the CSS display property to `inline-block` if you want to read its width.

You can define it in the main page:

```
<head>
  <style>
    span[slot=username] {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Or in the Shadow DOM via the `::slotted()` CSS pseudo-element:

```
<style>
  ::slotted(span[slot=username]) {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;         
  }
</style>
```

```js
customElements.define('user-card', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .innerHTML = `
      <style>
        div.name {
          font-size: 24px;
          width: 200px;
          background-color: yellow;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        ::slotted(span[slot="username"]) {
          display: inline-block; 
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="name">Name :
        <slot name="username"></slot>
      </div>
      <div class="dob">Birthday:
        <slot name="birthday"></slot>
      </div>
    `
  }
})

function abc(event) {
  console.log('Expected: ', this.document.getElementsByTagName('user-card')[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('.name').offsetWidth)
  console.log('Result: ', event.target.parentElement.offsetWidth)
}
```

```html
<user-card>
  <span slot="username">
    <div onclick="abc(event)">Ritesh Rajput</div>
  </span>
  <span slot="birthday">01.01.2001</span>
</user-card>
```